# Form Re-Submission using Codeigniter with POST data

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

Hi all I have a CI controller which does things such as:

```
$this->loadEditingView($this->input->post('cleaned_post_data'));
```

which leaves the URL at the method that ran the above line such as:

```
mysite.com/project/main/editclasses
```

the problem I am having is that the I post alot of data and reload the view - meaning if the page is refreshed the form is re-submitted. I believe I can't use a redirect as the post data will be seen in the URL? what is the best way to prevent the annoying form re-submission

Comment: Of course you can use `redirect()` to prevent any form-resubmission.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the post data in session variable and unset it after use.

Answer (score 0):

Your POST Data will not be shown on the URL when you redirect with `redirect()` method. That's not how it works, read about method here:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html